# store parameter of link in variable then display in span tag next to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to store the number after team_id= then display it in the span tag below it. I attempted using slice to store the numbers but no luck.

```html
<div class="link"><a href="http://test/site/TR/ooo/General-ooo?team_id=3912&pg=team&event_id=1014">The Wolves</a>
<span></span>
</div>
<div class="link"><a href="http://test/site/TR/ooo/General-ooo?team_id=3912&pg=team&event_id=1060">The Tigers</a>
<span></span>
</div>
```

The point is to pull the number from the URL then have it display in the corresponding span tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
$("div.link a").each(function() {
  let $this = $(this),
      url = $this.attr("href").match(/team_id=(\d+)/);
      
  $this.next("span").text(url[1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link"><a href="http://test/site/TR/ooo/General-ooo?team_id=3912&pg=team&event_id=1014">The Wolves</a>
<span></span>
</div>
<div class="link"><a href="http://test/site/TR/ooo/General-ooo?team_id=3912&pg=team&event_id=1060">The Tigers</a>
<span></span>
</div>
```

Explanation:

- `$("div.link a").each(function() {` - Selects all anchors under `div`'s with class `link`;
- `url = $this.attr("href").match(/team_id=(\d+)/);` - Gets the url section with `team_id` and the following number;
- `$this.next("span").text(url[1]);` - Sets the text of the `span` next to the current anchor, the number taken from url.